# Testing a Dart API wrapper

Tags: dart

I am currently writing an API wrapper for wit.ai. I'd like to add tests to this wrapper but I am unsure how I'd do that given that I'm using the `http` library to send HTTP requests.

The code would look something like this:

```
Future message(String q) {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.wit.${apiVersion}+json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}'
    };
    return http
        .get('https://api.wit.ai/message?q=${q}', headers: headers)
        .then((response) {
      return JSON.decode(response.body);
    }).catchError((e, stackTrace) {
      return JSON.decode(e);
    });
  }
```

Given this code, how would I write a test that does not actually send a HTTP request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is traditionally solved by dependency injection. Your API wrapper class could have a constructor like:

```
class MyWrapper {
  final http.BaseClient _httpClient;
  MyWrapper({BaseClient httpClient: new http.Client()})
      : _httpClient = httpClient;

  // ...
}
```

Using a named argument with a default value means normal users won't need to worry about creating the [Client](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/http/0.11.3%2B7/http/Client-class.html).

In your method, you use the `Client` instead of using the static methods of the `http` library:

```
Future message(String q) {
  Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.wit.${apiVersion}+json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}'
  };
  return _httpClient
      .get('https://api.wit.ai/message?q=${q}', headers: headers)
      .then((response) {
    return JSON.decode(response.body);
  }).catchError((e, stackTrace) {
    return JSON.decode(e);
  });
}
```

Keep in mind, though, that clients need to be closed. If you don't have a `close` method on your API wrapper, you may want to a) add it, or b) put the dependency injection on the `message()` method instead of on the constructor.

When testing, [set up a `MockClient`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/http/0.11.3%2B7/testing/testing-library.html). Pass it like so:

```
var wrapper = new MyWrapper(httpClient: myMockClient);
```

No need for running a local server, and way faster.